# What's the point of csscomb.json in twitter bootstrap less directory?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

csscomb.js plugin works just with css files, am I right ?

Is the file there so that you can later reprocess the css file once less files are compiled or maybe I'm missing the correct way to use this file ?

Answer (score 0):

[CSScomb](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/CSScomb%20JS) is a coding style formatter for CSS.

You can easily write your own configuration to make your stylesheets beautiful
and consistent.

CSScomb, a tool to help you sort and categorize CSS properties in your code to improve maintenance. CSScomb is a utility to sort CSS properties within each selector declaration in a predefined order. The CSScomb algorithm is intended to be as close as possible to the choices a Web developer would make when working on CSS code. In order to re-sort, it is would usually be necessary to cut and paste lines, taking into consideration comments, multiline values, hacks — everything you would encounter in any serious project. This task is fairly dull to do by hand: you can trust CSScomb to do it for you.

more details [here](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/10/02/csscomb-tool-sort-css-properties/)

Comment: Ok but what's the point of including csscomb.json file in bootstrap less project folder if i cannot use it with less files ? is it just to reorder bootstrap.css file once compiled ?

Comment: @user3786211 Correct.

Comment: It is there so that once you make changes to less and recomile it compiled code is virtually identical in formatting and organization. This replaces the CSSLint